# Open a image my app to Adobe Lightroom app android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

Im trying to open my app image to another app

I have image uri in my android app , I want to open it directly android adobe lightroom app with kotlin

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez I need a simple solution where I have an image URI and I need to send this image directly to the adobe lightroom app for editing that image. Thanks for the suggestion and I got the way to do this. I give it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my requirements

here's the code:

```
val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                    setPackage("com.adobe.lrmobile")
                    type = "image/jpeg"
                }
                startActivity(shareIntent)
```